¿Es posible convertir una cadena de bytes dentro de un char* a su valor en un float en GNU C?
Estoy extrayendo datos de un registro BLOB de una base de datos sqlite3 a través de GNU C. La realidad es que tengo poquísima experiencia con GNU C y me está costando mucho solucionar mi problema. Estoy seguro de que es un tontería. ¡Perdonadme si la respuesta es muy obvia!
He conseguido una cadena de datos a través de esta función:
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   return 0;
}

En este caso, el resultado impreso es:
CoordX = AD1E9844

No tengo ni idea de cómo obtener el valor float de AD1E9844 (que debería ser 1216.96 en este caso).
¡Necesito ayuda! Como he comentado, es un char* el que contiene "AD1E9844" y no sé como efectuar la conversión (o si es posible).
Olvidando la fuente que ha generado el dato la pregunta es cómo llego de
char* argv[i] -> Contiene "AD1E9844"

a
char valor[] = {0xAD, 0x1E, 0x98, 0x44};

¡Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda!

No sé de sqlite, pero no creo que sea un tema de tipos. Si AD1E9844 son los bytes del float, puedes usar una conversión (float*) o tal vez tengas que cambiar el orden de los bytes primero.

Por alguna razón estas leyendo de forma plana una base sqlite y no estás usando la
API oficial?

Hola Patricio, estoy utilizando la libreria de gcc para sqlite3. (#include <sqlite3.h>) -> sqlite-devel-3.26.0-19.el8_9.x86_64.

Si los datos están en un blob debes usar las funciones para leer blobs (https://sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_open) . Sin ver la query y la definición de la tabla no podemos dar más detalles

Mil gracias a Mady, ROOR y PaperBirdMaster por la ayuda, finalmente la aportación de PaperBirdMaster me iluminó y este es el resultado (aprovechando una función denominada datahex ya creada por otro usuario):
u_int8_t* datahex(char* string) {

    if(string == NULL)
       return NULL;

    size_t slength = strlen(string);
    if((slength % 2) != 0) // must be even
       return NULL;

    size_t dlength = slength / 2;

    u_int8_t* data = malloc(dlength);
    memset(data, 0, dlength);

    size_t index = 0;
    while (index < slength) {
        char c = string[index];
        int value = 0;
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
          value = (c - '0');
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
          value = (10 + (c - 'A'));
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
          value = (10 + (c - 'a'));
        else {
          free(data);
          return NULL;
        }

        data[(index/2)] += value << (((index + 1) % 2) * 4);

        index++;
    }

    return data;
}


Ejemplo de llamada a la función datahex, basado en la idea de PaperBirdMaster.
(En este caso, argv[i] tiene un valor "AD1E9844")

u_int8_t* Cx = datahex(argv[i]);
float resultado;
memcpy(&resultado, Cx, 4);
printf("CoordX (%s) %.02f \n", argv[i] ,resultado);


El resultado es 100% correcto:
CoordX (AD1E9844) 1216.96


Creo que no hay mucha diferencia en rendimiento, pero también puedes convertir de dígito a número (del 0 al 9) con c & 15.

Copia directamente en un float:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char valor[] = {0xAD, 0x1E, 0x98, 0x44};
    float decimal;

    memcpy(&decimal, valor, 4);

    printf("%.02f", decimal);

    return 0;
}

El código anterior produce la siguiente salida:
1216.96


dispongo de un valor char* que contiene "AD1E9844" y no sé cómo pasar del char* a el char que estás indicando

Si tienes el puntero a los caracteres (char *) ya tienes todo lo necesario:
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    for (i = 0; i != argc; ++i)
    {
        float resultado;
        memcpy(&resultado, argv[i], sizeof(float));
        printf("%s = %.02f\n", azColName[i], resultado);
    }

    return 0;
}


Por cierto, asegúrate de que el float sea de 4 bytes en tu plataforma.

Exacto PaperBirdMaster, ese es el punto donde debo llegar, pero el problema es que dispongo de un valor char* que contiene "AD1E9844" y no sé cómo pasar del char* a el char que estás indicando. Tal vez debería editar la pregunta porque ese es exactamente el problema que tengo. Gracias por tu ayuda!

sscanf (argv[i], "%02x%02x%02x%02x", &valor[0], &valor[1], &valor[2], &valor[3]);, pero no deberías usar un BLOB para almacenar un dato que es soportado por la base de datos. Si necesitas almacenar floats usa NUM o REAL, Esta solución no es portable y tendrás problemas si compilas en máquinas con distinta endianess

Creo que con lo que puso PaperBirdMaster y ROOR ya es suficiente, pero igual dejo un ejemplo completo:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arg[] = "ad1e9844"; // recibido de argv
    
    // se leen los cuatro bytes del float.
    // %x es el formato para "entero sin signo en hexadecimal"
    // asi que se necesitan estas variables temporales
    unsigned int a, b, c, d; 

    sscanf (arg, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    // se inicializa el arreglo de bytes que sera copiado a la variable float 
    char valor[] = {a, b, c, d};

    // se "reinterpretan" los bytes como un float
    float decimal;
    memcpy(&decimal, valor, 4);
    printf("%.02f", decimal); // 1216.96

    return 0;
}


@RoadRat te dejo una implementación alternativa.
El código simplemente convierte cada byte de ASCII a hex y solo funciona en máquinas Little Endian y por lo tanto no es portable. Cada dos dígitos hexadecimales son 1 byte por eso procesamos de dos en dos y le damos la vuelta a los nibbles (grupos de 4 bits que representan un dígito hex).
El &0x4f convierte minúsculas a mayúsculas y los digitos 0-9 a su valor numérico. Si el valor es mayor que 10 (tendríamos una letra), hay que restar 0x37 para convertir a valor numérico. Luego solo desplazamos el grupo de 4 bits a la posición que le corresponde dentro del entero en memoria
Finalmente convertimos a  float y retornamos el valor final.
#include <stdio.h>

float datahex (char *v1) {
  char *p = v1;
  float f1;
  int *q = (int *)&f1;
  char v;
  
  for (int i=0; *p; i+=2) {
    *q |= (((v = *p++ &0x4f) > 10 ? v-=0x37 : v) << (4*(i+1)));
    *q |= (((v = *p++ &0x4f) > 10 ? v-=0x37 : v) << (4*i));
  }
  return *(float*)q;

}

int main () {
  char *v1="AD1E9844";

  printf ("%s : %f\n", v1, datahex(v1));
}


